# Create subquery with spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have problem with querydsl using spring-data-jpa 1.2.0.RELEASE

I have Entity Item which has set of Promotions and each promotion has PromotionType which is an Enum. I am trying to find all items which contains set of filtered promotions where PromotionType == PromotionType.Special. I think I'll achieve that with a subquery to set of promotions like this:

Predicate:

```
public class ItemPredicates {
    private static QItem $ = QItem.item;

    public static BooleanExpression getSpecialItems() {
        return $.promotions.any().promotionType.eq(PromotionType.SPECIAL);
    }
}

Test:

//prepare data
Item item = new Item();
item.setPromotions(Sets.newHashSet(promotion(PromotionType.SPECIAL), promotion(PromotionType.NORMAL)));

//assertion
Item specialItems = itemRepository.findOne(ItemPredicates.getSpecialItems());
```

So I'd expected item with filtered out promotions with only special type of promotion, instead I always get an item which have set of promotions. If I'll change test to this:

```
Test:

//prepare data
Item item = new Item();
item.setPromotions(Sets.newHashSet(promotion(Promo tionType.NORMAL)));

//assertion
Item specialItems = itemRepository.findOne(ItemPredicates.getSpecialItems());
```

Then I'll get no item which is correct. But how to filter set of promotions to have only SPECIAL promotion type?

Please could you give me a hand with it?